# How to turn a file path into a socket struct?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

I'm trying to implement a server that works via UDS for an assignment and I have no idea what I'm doing. One of the input arguments to run the main function is a UDS path string. We are told that this needs to be unlinked before `bind` can be called.

Right now I have this:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
     if ( argc != 3 )
         return usage( argv[0] );

    log_fd = fopen(argv[1], "a");

    // create a server socket
    // domain (i.e., family) is AF_UNIX
    // type is SOCK_STREAM
    int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);     

    socklen_t clientLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    struct sockaddr clientAddr;
    clientAddr.sa_family = AF_INET;

    pthread_t tid;

    // unlink the UDS path)
    unlink(argv[2]);

    // bind the server socket
    bind(listenfd, (SA *)&clientAddr, clientLength);    

    // listen
    listen(listenfd, 1024);
    // loop to wait for connections;
    // as each connection is accepted,
    // launch a new thread that calls
    // recv_log_msgs(), which receives
    // messages and writes them to the log file
    while(1){
        printf( "Waiting for a connection on UDS path %s...\n", argv[2] );
        int * clientfdp = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *clientfdp = accept(listenfd, (SA *) &clientAddr, &clientLength);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, recv_log_msgs, clientfdp);
    }

    // when the loop ends, close the listening socket
    close(listenfd);        

    // close the log file
    fclose(log_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

where the UDS path entered by the user is `argv[2]`. As you can see, I never really use it other than to unlink it, which doesn't really make sense. Is the UDS path suppossed to be what I am passing as a `bind` argument somehow? If so, how do I get it from a path to a `struct sockaddr`?

Edit:

So I had to change the type of `clientAddr` to `strcut sockaddr_un`, and the family to `AF_UNIX`. Now, the struct has a pathname value that I should be able to set. But now, when I try

`clientAddr.sun_path = argv[2];`

I get an error when I compile:

`error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[108]' from type 'char *'

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you need unix sockets, why AF_INET?

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, see my edit

Comment: Read about `strncpy`.

Comment: argv[2] and clientAddr.sun_path are a pointer to a character array and an array. You can't simply assign arrays in C. You need to *copy the elements* across

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, got rid of the error. And now that they're finally gone... the code doesn't work whatsoever

Comment: If you'd tell us *what you have done* and *what doesn't work*, we could maybe even help you ;)

Comment: @tofro Sure. I made a new thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914726/why-wont-my-uds-server-accept-connections