# Why won't my UDS server accept connections?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a small UDS server for an assignment, and feel that my code is mostly there, but I am getting absolutely no results when I actually try to run it.

The code is tested by a shell script which sends several different test calls to the main function of my code. The only things passed to main are a `log` file name, and a `UDS path`, and then different clients connect to the server, which should simply result in a particular output log to check for correctness of the sever code.

My main function is here:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
     if ( argc != 3 )
         return usage( argv[0] );

    log_fd = fopen(argv[1], "a");

    // create a server socket
    // domain (i.e., family) is AF_UNIX
    // type is SOCK_STREAM
    int listenfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);     

    socklen_t clientLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
    struct sockaddr_un clientAddr;
    clientAddr.sa_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(clientAddr.sun_path, argv[2]);

    pthread_t tid;

    // unlink the UDS path)
    unlink(argv[2]);

    // bind the server socket
    bind(listenfd, (SA *)&clientAddr, clientLength);    

    // listen
    listen(listenfd, 1024);
    // loop to wait for connections;
    // as each connection is accepted,
    // launch a new thread that calls
    // recv_log_msgs(), which receives
    // messages and writes them to the log file
    while(1){
        printf( "Waiting for a connection on UDS path %s...\n", argv[2] );
        int * clientfdp = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *clientfdp = accept(listenfd, (SA *) &clientAddr, &clientLength);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, recv_log_msgs, clientfdp);
    }

    // when the loop ends, close the listening socket
    close(listenfd);        

    // close the log file
    fclose(log_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

where the usage is `myloggerd <log-file-name> <UDS path>`.

This main function listens for any client connections, and when one is accepted, it creates a new thread at the thread routine function called `recv_log_msgs`. My code for that is here:

```
void * recv_log_msgs( void * arg ) //Thread Routine
{
    // loops to receive messages from a client;
    // when the connection is closed by the client,
    // close the socket
    int clientfd = *((int *)arg);
    char buffer[1500];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1500);
    int currentPos = 0;
    int bytesRec;
    int recvng = 1;

    while(recvng){
        bytesRec = recv(clientfd, buffer, 1500-currentPos, 0);
        currentPos += bytesRec;
        if(buffer[currentPos - 1] == '\n')
            recvng = 0;
    }

    fprintf(log_fd, "LOGGER %d %s", clientfd, buffer);
    close(clientfd);
    return NULL;
}
```

So, each time a thread enters this function, data is written to the log file. If the log file turns out correct, then I get a 100%. If not, then I fail.

As of right now, when I test my solution, nothing happens at all.

I get an infinite loop of prints that say `Waiting for connection on the UDS path...`, which is inside the `while` at the end of main. Shouldn't this not continue to loop one I have made the call to `accept` and created the thread, until that thread has exited?

Comment: ` if(buffer[currentPos - 1] == '\n')` that can't work. Whether you find newlines or not depends on the chunk sizes you get.

Comment: What do you mean? That line was taken from my textbook
Edit: But that is beside the point of my immediate concern since my code isn't even reaching that function.

Comment: Take note that `recv` can return `0` and also `-1` on first iteration. This means _Undefined Behaviour_ on `buffer[currentPos - 1]`

Comment: You have to call [pthread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) to wait for a thread termination.

Comment: Also note that functions like *accept()* and *listen()* tend to return an error code every now and then - Especially if things are not working. You want to check for negative numbers and then *errno*

Comment: @LPs But should't `accept` block regardless? I am getting an infinite loop before any client ever tries to connect, so I don't see why it is getting passed the `accept`

Comment: That is exactly why you should check for error codes - Accept not blocking hints to an error there

Comment: @tofro Good thinking, I will check now and report back

Comment: @tofro It has to be a bad file descriptor. `listenfd` was originally declared as `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`; This only started once I changed `AF_INET` to `AF_UNIX`. I don't know why it's causing an error though

Comment: @tofro All the errno  gives me is "Invalid argument"

Comment: Take notes that you have a memory leak due to `malloc` inside the loop without a `free`.

Answer (score 0):

You are mismatching the type of `clientAddr` for the `AF_UNIX` socket: have to be `struct sockaddr`

This worked for me:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
     if ( argc != 3 )
         return -1;

//    log_fd = fopen(argv[1], "a");

    // create a server socket
    // domain (i.e., family) is AF_UNIX
    // type is SOCK_STREAM
    int listenfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    socklen_t clientLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
    struct sockaddr clientAddr;
    clientAddr.sa_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(clientAddr.sa_data, argv[2]);

    pthread_t tid;

    // unlink the UDS path)
    unlink(argv[2]);

    // bind the server socket
    bind(listenfd, (struct  sockaddr*)&clientAddr, clientLength);

    // listen
    listen(listenfd, 1024);
    // loop to wait for connections;
    // as each connection is accepted,
    // launch a new thread that calls
    // recv_log_msgs(), which receives
    // messages and writes them to the log file
    while(1){
        printf( "Waiting for a connection on UDS path %s...\n", argv[2] );
        int * clientfdp = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *clientfdp = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &clientLength);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, recv_log_msgs, clientfdp);
        free(clientfdp);
    }

    // when the loop ends, close the listening socket
    close(listenfd);

    // close the log file
//    fclose(log_fd);

    return 0;
}
```